# How to deselect selected row of table layout dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, dynamic, row, highlight

Below line for bodyrow of table for containing textviews

```
TableRow bodyRow1 = new TableRow(CallActivity.this);
```

Below code for highlight the row of tablelayout dynamically

```
bodyRow1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); // set green color for selected row on screen
        }
   }

tblItemDetail.addView(bodyRow1);  //here row added to tablelayout
```

Comment: Thanks in advance.....Please guide me

Comment: its new for me..

Comment: can you able elaborate your question so that we can easily find out your issue

Comment: what I want to do is have the table row start of transparent. When someone clicks on the table row I want it to change to green color. Then, if they click it again, I want it to change back to transparent.